# What is the length of side AB of the triangle?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, plane-geometry

Point X is 3m from A, 4m from B and 5m from C. Point X is inside the triangle formed by ABC. If AB = BC and angle B is right angle. Find the length of side AB.

I have come up with the following figure and aware that this is an isosceles right triangle, unfortunately i'm not sure what to do next.

[image]

Comment: You might try setting up coordinates for points A,B,C and letting X be $(x,y)$. Then write three distance equations for the given lengths. Of course initially there will be a parameter in the coordinates for A,B,C which will somehow have to be eliminated once you have the equations.

Comment: This should be what you need, using law of cosines. https://mathalino.com/reviewer/plane-geometry/03-point-p-inside-isosceles-right-triangle

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assign coordinates to the 4 given points. B = $(0,0)$, C = $(L,0)$, A = $(0,L)$, X = $(x, y)$.

Apply Pythagoras to the three line segments.

1. $$x^2 +y^2 = 16$$
2. $$(L-x)^2 + y^2 = 25$$
3. $$x^2 + (L-y)^2 = 9$$

Combining 1. and 2. gives $L^2 - 2Lx = 9$ and therefore $x = (L^2-9)/(2L)$

Combining 1. and 3. gives $L^2 - 2Ly = -7$ and therefore $y = (L^2 +7)/(2L)$

You can now substitute these expressions for $x$ and $y$ into equation 1 and solve for $L$. The result is $L = \sqrt{17 + \sqrt{224}}$, which is approximately 5.6539.

Comment: The equation for L has a fourth order, a second order and a constant term. Set M = L^2. Then you have a quadratic equation in M which can be solved in the usual way.

Comment: Have you tried it? It's a simple biquadratic equation ...

Answer (score 2):

[image]

Reflect point $X$ across the sides of $\triangle ABC$. Observe,
$$\begin{align*}
\angle DAF&=\angle DAX+\angle FAX=2(\angle BAX+\angle CAX)=90^{\circ}\;\implies DF=3\sqrt{2}\\
\angle DCE&=\angle DCX+\angle ECX=2(\angle ACX+\angle BCX)=90^{\circ}\;\implies DE=5\sqrt{2}\\
\angle FBE&=\angle FBX+\angle EBX=2(\angle ABX+\angle CBX)=180^{\circ}\implies F,\;B,\;E \;\;\text{are collinear.}
\end{align*}
$$
Using the cosine rule, in $\triangle EDF,$
$$\begin{align*}
EF^2&=DE^2+DF^2-2\cdot DE\cdot DF\cdot\cos\angle EFD \\
64&=18+50-60\cdot\cos\angle EFD \\
\cos \angle EFD&=\frac{1}{15} \implies \sin\angle EFD=\frac{4\sqrt{14}}{15}
\end{align*} $$
Using the cosine rule, in $\triangle ADC,$
$$\begin{align*}
AC^2 &=AD^2+CD^2-2\cdot AD\cdot CD\cdot \cos\angle ADC\\
 &=9+25-30\cos(90^{\circ}+\angle EFD)\\
&=34+30\cdot\sin\angle EFD\\
&=34+8\sqrt{14} \\ \\
\therefore\; AB&=\sqrt{\frac{AC^2}{2}}=\boxed{\sqrt{17+4\sqrt{14}}\approx 5.6539}
\end{align*}$$

Comment: Which interface did you use for drawing the figure? Pretty nice (+1)

Comment: [GeoGebra](https://www.geogebra.org/geometry?lang=en)

Comment: @SathvikAcharya : Please see my construction. I request you to comment on it.

Answer (score 0):

Comment

To construct the triangle in Geogebra I drew three concentric circles radii 3,4,5  for A,B,C respectively with X as center. Constructed a slidable right angle  with 90 deg vertex at B. Drawn arc with radius 5.654 units from B to locate A and C as shown.

However got a different location of X inside the triangle with
hypotenue AC almost 8 units long and X is almost on side AC.
What may be my construction error?

[image]

Comment: If you found points $A,C$ by constructing a circle centered at $B$ with radius 5.654 and finding the intersection points, how is the length of segment $BC=8$?

Comment: Typo corrected, else all ok.

Comment: Point $X$ is inside the triangle  and all the conditions are perfectly satisfied. So it seems correct. (My figure is not drawn to scale)